# Parsing and sanitizing JSON in Swift causes a lot a duplicate code

Tags: json, swift, swift2

I have a hierarchy of 2 classes: `Person` and its subclass, `SuperHero`. Both should be created from a `JSON` representation that comes from a web service:

```
class Person {
    let name : String
    let surname : String

    init(name: String, surname: String){
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    }
}

class SuperHero : Person {

    let alias : String
    let superpowers : String

    init(name: String, surname: String, alias: String, superpowers: String){


        self.alias = alias
        self.superpowers = superpowers

        super.init(name: name, surname: surname)

    }
}
```

Once I get the `Dictionary` returned by `NSJSONSerialization`, I want to make sure that the dictionary contains all the correct keys and values to create instances of `Person` or `SuperHero`...and this is where I run into trouble.

I have 2 functions that take a `[String: AnyObject]` and return a `Person` and a `SuperHero` respectively. However, with functions have way too much code in common:

```
 // JSON Processing
typealias JSONObject        = AnyObject
typealias JSONDictionary    = [String:JSONObject]

enum JSONParsingError : ErrorType{

    case SomethingWentWrong
}

func decodeJSON(person json: JSONDictionary) throws -> Person{

    // Make sure the json is correct
    guard let firstName = json["name"] as? String,
        let lastName  = json["surname"] as? String else{
            throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
    }

    return Person(name: firstName, surname: lastName)
}


func decodeJSON(superHero json: JSONDictionary) throws ->SuperHero{

    // Make sure the json is correct
    guard let firstName = json["name"] as? String,
        let lastName  = json["surname"] as? String else{
            throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
    }

    // Make sure it has an alias and superpowers
    guard let alias = json["alias"] as? String,
        let superpowers = json["superpowers"] as? String else{
            throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
    }

    return SuperHero(name: firstName, surname: lastName, alias: alias, superpowers: superpowers)

}
```

`decodeJSON(superhero:String)` does almost the same thing that `decodeJSON(person:String)` does, plus some extra stuff.

The only difference is the return value and some of the checks on the input they do.

I'm pretty sure there must be a more elegant solution. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach might be to store the dictionary as an instance variable and use computed properties for name, surname etc.:

```
typealias JSONObject        = Any
typealias JSONDictionary    = [String:JSONObject]

enum JSONParsingError : ErrorType {
    case SomethingWentWrong
}

class Person {
    let json : JSONDictionary
    var name : String { return json["name"] as? String ?? "" }
    var surname : String { return json["surname"] as? String ?? "" }

    init(json: JSONDictionary) throws {
        self.json = json
        guard
            let _ = json["name"] as? String,
            let _ = json["surname"] as? String
            else {
                throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
        }
    }
}

class SuperHero: Person {
    var alias : String { return json["alias"] as? String ?? "" }
    var superpowers : String { return json["superpowers"] as? String ?? "" }

    override init(json: JSONDictionary) throws {
        try super.init(json: json)
        guard
            let _ = json["alias"] as? String,
            let _ = json["superpowers"] as? String
            else {
                throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
        }
    }
}
```

or, in a more DRY way:

```
class JSONEntity {
    let json : JSONDictionary

    init(json: JSONDictionary) throws {
        self.json = json
    }

    func checkAsString(keys: String ...) throws {
        for k in keys {
            guard let _ = json[k] as? String else {
                throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person : JSONEntity {
    var name : String { return json["name"] as? String ?? "" }
    var surname : String { return json["surname"] as? String ?? "" }

    override init(json: JSONDictionary) throws {
        try super.init(json: json)
        try checkAsString("name", "surname")
    }
}

class SuperHero: Person {
    var alias : String { return json["alias"] as? String ?? "" }
    var superpowers : String { return json["superpowers"] as? String ?? "" }

    override init(json: JSONDictionary) throws {
        try super.init(json: json)
        try checkAsString("alias", "superpowers")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `decodeJSON(person` from `decodeJSON(superHero`.

Comment: But I'll get a Person, not a SuperHero.

Comment: Get the `firstName` and lastName` from the person. There are other ways, create a version of the `decodeJSON(person` method to return a tuple an use that ,method on both of the current methods. There is also the point that `SuperHero` is a subclass of a `Person` and that is not being used.

Answer (score -1):

```
extension Dictionary {
  func asString(forKey: Key) throws -> String {
    if let result = self[forKey] as? String { return result }
    throw JSONParsingError.SomethingWentWrong
  }
}

func decodeJSON(person json: JSONDictionary) throws -> Person {
  return Person(
    name   : try json.asString("name"),
    surname: try json.asString("surname")
  )
}

func decodeJSON(superHero json: JSONDictionary) throws -> SuperHero {
  return SuperHero(
    name       : try json.asString("name"),
    surname    : try json.asString("surname"),
    alias      : try json.asString("alias"),
    superpowers: try json.asString("superpowers")
  )
}
```